# Replacing only exact match

Tags: java

I have a String and some similar words of that as below:-

```
String sentence = "I have @ty and @ty-1 and @ty-2 as a sentence";
```

When I say

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("@ty", "space");
```

Output is like :-

```
sentence = "I have space and space-1 and space-2 as a sentence";
```

But the desired output is

```
sentence = "I have space and @ty-1 and @ty-2 as a sentence";
```

I also Tried

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("@ty\\b", "space");
```

Even this isn't giving right output.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Will the end of the string always `;` ?

Comment: @NinadPingale it is a java `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("@ty(?!\\-)", "space");
```

**Explanation:**
`(?!\\-)` is a negative lookahead, which means that we're looking only for `@ty` which is not followed by a dash `-`.

Comment: What about other symbols after `@ty`? The regex will have to be extended for each possible case right?

Comment: @shree.pat18 right, but it won't be difficult to do

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to recognize a *special* word boundary. As you said, you already tried the "\b" word boundary that is built into the regular expression syntax. Unfortunately, that will also trigger on the symbols "@" and "-".

It seems that you only want to work on space boundaries. So you must write it yourself. Go with that expression:

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("(?<=\\s+)@ty(?=\\s+)", "space");
```

Explanation: The part `(?<=\\s+)` is called a *positive lookbehind* that only looks for spaces. The part `(?=\\s+)` is called a *positive lookahead*. These lookarounds try to match characters without consuming them, so you can easily use the expression to only replace the "@ty" part with your desired "space".

For more information look at this [regex tutorial about lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: when I try this I get compile error. removing the +s seems to work

Answer (score 2):

Here is my regex:

```
@ty(?= |$)
```

This uses a lookahead Expression. It means "@ty followed by a space or the end of the string". I tested the regex at this Website http://regex101.com/ with the following teststring and the "g" modifier:

"I have @ty and @ty-1 and @ty-2 as a sentence @ty"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to escape the `@` symbol and ensure the next character is whitespace and then you could use [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
String sentence = "I have @ty and @ty-1 and @ty-2 as a sentence";
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("\\@ty(\\s)", "space ");
System.out.println(sentence);
```

Output is the specified

```
I have space and @ty-1 and @ty-2 as a sentence
```

Comment: This works good for my scenario , but will this replaceFirst works if there are 2 @ty in the sentence?

Comment: @PRATHAPS Edited. For that, use `replaceAll`.

Comment: In case
` String sentence = "I have @tyand @ty-1 and @ty-2 as a sentence"; `

Comment: @PRATHAPS Then you have no "exact match".

Comment: Yes , I was just checking if there are any possibilities , 
Okay thanks for your answer, It is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, you can also do that without the use of regular expressions, but it will be very inefficient:

```
    String sentence = "I have @ty and @ty-1 and @ty-2 as a sentence";
    String []split = sentence.split("\\s");
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
        if (split[i].equals("@ty")){
            split[i] = "space";
        }
    }

   sentence =  org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(split, " ");
   System.out.println(sentence);
```